# compiler asked me to include a return statement even though I have already included one

Tags: java, return

I'm new to Java and is trying to solve the beginner's problem of finding the next prime number after a given number. Below are the two version of the solution I came up with. For the first version, the compiler is asking me to include a second return statement (i.e. return 0;) at the end of findNextNumber method eventhough I have already included a return statement within the code, while the second version did not ask me to include an extra return statement. Could someone please tell me why this is the case? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    public static int findNextPrime(int num) {

// VERSION 1
//        boolean isPrime = false;
//        while(!isPrime){
//            num += 1;
//            int sqt = (int)Math.sqrt(num);
//            for(int i = 2; i <= sqt; i++){
//                if(num % i == 0){
//                    break;
//                } else {
//                    isPrime = true;
//                    return num;
//                }
//            }
//        }
//        return 0;

// VERSION 2       
//        while (true) {
//            boolean isPrime = true;
//            num += 1;
//            int sqt = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
//            for (int i = 2; i <= sqt; i++) {
//                if (num % i == 0) {
//                    isPrime = false;
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
//            if (isPrime) {
//                return num;
//            }
//        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second version, the compiler knows that `while(true) {...}` can only be exited by your return statement.

In the first version, the compiler sees that the condition isn't constant, and assumes that `while(!isPrime) {...}` might exit the loop because `isPrime` is true.  You and I know that this can't happen, but the language won't let you rely on that to omit the return statement.

Change `while(!isPrime)` to `while(true)` or `for(;;)` if you are sure that `isPrime` is always false there.